# "Robot detection failed". Why?

Tags: discussion, bug, captcha

I got a "Robot detection failed" error message. What can be the cause?

[image]

I did click in the checkbox where I am supposed to click to prove that I am human. I was using the same computer, IP, and browser as usual.

Comment: Well, [the official announcement](https://security.googleblog.com/2014/12/are-you-robot-introducing-no-captcha.html) is not giving and concrete details, most likely on purpose to not make the spammer's life easier. But my guess is that you were too fast to click the checkbox, or something like that.

Comment: On second thought, this error might have come from SE side, when internal error occurred when they were using the reCAPTCHA API. This only SE dev can confirm. (So, adding a [tag:bug] tag just in case)

Comment: There's a separate error message when our server fails to reach recaptcha. The message op got is shown when the `https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/siteverify` [API response](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify) is like `{ "success": false, ... }`

Comment: @m0sa sounds fair enough, why not answer? :)

Comment: @Franck according to [this](https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=reCAPTCHA+API+%22success%22+false) you might have clicked the checkbox twice in a row, thus submitting the form twice and triggering this error. Can this be the case? (and do you still get this error?)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Thanks, interesting, that can definitely be the case (I use a quite sensitive dwell clicking software). I haven't met the captcha again so far.

Comment: @m0sa please see OP response, in such case can you make the checkbox disabled after the first click to prevent this error?

Comment: The captcha checkbox is rendered in an iframe from google, it's not controlled by us

Comment: I think the obvious cause is that you, Frank, are a robot.

Comment: @Won't: You beat me by 30 minutes.

Comment: Isn't that good? (Question)